# Im trying to use backgroundworker i want to see the upload progress but it dosent work why?

Tags: c#

In the designer i put backgroundworker and i have two events: Do Work and Progress Changed.
I used breakpoint and its getting inside the Do Work event but it never get into the Progress Changed event. Its never stop there like the event isnt working. Why the progrss changed event isnt working ?

This is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Google.GData.Client;
using Google.GData.Extensions;
using Google.GData.Extensions.MediaRss;
using Google.GData.YouTube;
using Google.YouTube;
using System.Threading;



namespace YoutubeTesting
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        YouTubeRequestSettings settings;
        YouTubeRequest request;
        string devkey = "AI39si6xhSQXx95FTYIACWPfq-lLIphblgaReuz9z6VEjR1Q6YjrV6FRN2U6FN6P6-lGF2OYaUZhCVOKJ_MCk4o6kPeUszvf5A";
        string username = "chocolade13091972@gmail.com";
        string password = "password";

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            worker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }




        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void upload()
        {
            try
            {
                settings = new YouTubeRequestSettings("You Manager", devkey, username, password);
                settings.Timeout = -1;
                request = new YouTubeRequest(settings);
                Video video = new Video();
                video.Title = "test";
                video.Tags.Add(new MediaCategory("Comedy", YouTubeNameTable.CategorySchema));
                video.Keywords = "Comedy";
                video.Private = false;
                video.MediaSource = new MediaFileSource("d:\\VIDEO0037.3gp", "video/3gp");
                request.Upload(video);
                MessageBox.Show("Successfully Uploaded");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            upload();
        }

        private void worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString();
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: What do you have right now that is supposed to be firing a ProgressChangedEvent? I think your problem is that you maybe are operating under the mistaken impression that request.Upload is going to magically invoke this for you, somehow.

Comment: Kevek can you show me example on my code then how to do it ? Thanks.

Comment: @DanielLip: If your `YouTubeRequest` does not provide you with progress you will not be able to do this in a meaningful way.

Answer (score 2):

You need to report the progress using `worker.ReportProgress()`

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ka89zff4.aspx):

> If you need the background operation to report on its progress, you
>   can call the ReportProgress method to raise the ProgressChanged event.
>   The WorkerReportsProgress property value must be true, or
>   ReportProgress will throw an InvalidOperationException.
>
> It is up to you to implement a meaningful way of measuring your
>   background operation's progress as a percentage of the total task
>   completed.
>
> The call to the ReportProgress method is asynchronous and returns
>   immediately. The ProgressChanged event handler executes on the thread
>   that created the BackgroundWorker.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.workerreportsprogress%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

```
backgroundWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
```

> Gets or sets a value indicating whether the BackgroundWorker can
>   report progress updates.

[image]

**EDIT**

If still not working checks whether you have bind the event properly in the designer code. Or just add something like below in your class.

```
backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged += new System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventHandler(this.worker_ProgressChanged);
```

In your Upload method you have to report progress. Otherwise above event won't fire. Keep in mind that, it's not easy to report actual progress always.

Below is an example code for a DoWork method. Look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7499659/windows-form-gui-gets-freezed-when-calling-the-thread-from-the-while-loop-how-to/7499744#7499744) if you want to see a complete example.

```
static void bw_DoWork (object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i += 20)
    {
      if (_bw.CancellationPending) { e.Cancel = true; return; }
      _bw.ReportProgress (i);
      Thread.Sleep (1000);      // Just for the demo... don't go sleeping
    }                           // for real in pooled threads!

    e.Result = 123;    // This gets passed to RunWorkerCompleted
  }
```

Comment: I changed it to true in the designer in the worker property. And also now i added this line to the constructor and its still not working.

Comment: @DanielLip: you have to report your progress using `ReportProgress(somePercentage)` from your work method

Comment: @DanielLip : See my edit. you have to call backgroundWorker.ReportProgress if you don't do that in the Update method.

Comment: Its working in general but i have in the do_work event upload(); and it dosent work cuz its going to the upload(); doing the upload. If i remove the upload(); its just counting fast to 99 thats it. But how do i connect this do_work with the for(int i = ).... with the upload(); ?

Comment: what i mean is how can i report the progress from inside the upload(); wich im calling inside the do_work event ? something like that i think.

Comment: @DanielLip: That's why I told it's not easy to Report Actual progress sometimes. If you don't have a way to calculate the progress of your Upload, that's a different question. May be you cannot report progress accurately. You may just show a progress bar without the percentage.

Comment: CharithJ ok i understand so how can i show just a progressbar without percentage ? lets say the code i have now and i also added a progressbar to the designer. how can i show the progressbar progress without percentage ? thep roblem is with the upload(); in the do_work event.

Comment: Another problem with the code i think is when a file is uploaded good in youtube.com in my account i see like the file uploaded 4-5 times at once and that only one of them is ok the others are rejected for duplicate. But why if im sending the file once i see it later after 10-15 minutes that it was uploaded like 4-5 times ?

Comment: A marquee-style progress indicator does not display progress; instead it indicates that an operation is occurring by moving the progress block across the progress bar. Google for examples

Comment: Not sure why it uploads multiple times. Make sure you have bind worker_DoWork to the BackgroundWorkder.DoWork only once. Add a breakpoint to the Upload method and check the TraceView and see how the execution comes there multiple times.

Comment: With regarding progress bar set the Style to Marqueee in order to get it worked without the percentage.